# is it possible to define 2 dimensional sets in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

Is it possible to define a 2 dimensional set in Javascript, which could look as follows:

```
let set = {}{};
```

and then to access this like a 2 dimensional array as `set[][];` ?

By the way, an Array is not suitable for my purpose, because I need to index with strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Do you mean "can an object's values be objects?" Because in that case: yes.

Comment: I'm no mathematician but I don't know what "2 dimensional set" means. *edit* I guess "set of sets"?

Comment: Give an example of what you want.

Comment: Also note that JavaScript has a Set type.

Comment: Sets don't have indexes, so "index with strings instead of numbers" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing doesn't seem like sets, you seem to be talking about an object whose values are other objects, e.g.

```
let set = {
    a: {x: 1, y: 2},
    b: {x: 10, y: 15}
}
```

You can then access this as `set.a.x` or `set['b']['y']`

Comment: I have a combobox of several types as innerHTML and to each type belong several ids. So in that case each value should be a set of the corresponding ids. The types and corresponding ids appear dynamically.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; and if you do, use backticks to delimit it, not [code].

Comment: the example you gave above is as similar as what I need. Is it possible to define it more general as: let set = {  {}, {} }  ?  I just tried it, but doesn't work

Comment: No, the elements of objects have to be `key: value` pairs. You can do `let set = {a: {}, b: {}}`. You can also just do `let set = {}` and you can add properties as needed like `set['a'] = {}`

Comment: what I want to archieve is as follows:                ids[type][id] = id;
                                                            option.value = ids[type][id];                          sorry, I have no idea, how to format code here

Comment: It won't automatically create nested objects for you. You can do `ids[type] = ids[type] || {}; ids[type][id] = id;`